# Content not appearing on scroll in Safari

Tags: html, css, web, safari

I made a site for a client recently and I've been told that they are seeing a bug that is safari specific. The site content fills up the browser window, but when they scroll down, the rest of the site will not load all the way. They fix this by resizing the browser window, in which case the rest of the content begins to appear.

I've tried to recreate this bug to no avail. Maybe you can? Or maybe you know what the issue is? I was thinking maybe an overflow problem?

the site is http://theherbalosophy.com

you can see a screenshot of the bug at http://michaelthomasrichards.com/bug.jpg

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: its not cut off for me in Safari, but the carousel is not working, so I'd start there...